# Looking for a recommendation for an AutoLisp / VisualLisp book

Tags: lisp, autolisp

Can anyone recommend a good introductionary book dealing with AutoLisp and VisualLisp?  I found some general Lisp books out there, but I'm uncertain how much Lisp variants differ.

I haven't found any in the old questions in here, either.

Comment: Lisp variants differ extensively.

Comment: In that case I'm specifically looking for an AutoLisp / VisualLisp book (those two being relatively similar).

Comment: Check out the forums etc in the Tag wiki. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info

Answer (score 4):

"The Visual LISP Developers Bible" by David M. Stein for example. It is from 2004, but AutoCAD autolisp/visual-lisp API has not changed during last years.

Answer (score 3):

You can view and download AutoLISP Books at following links:
[Autolisp Books](http://www.caddsoftsolutions.com/AutoLISP-VisualLISP-DCL-Books.htm)

Answer (score 1):

My first AutoLISP book was "The ABCs of AutoLISP" (available at the link Shantaram shared).  I really appreciated it.  It was short and it was a good primer for me in the early days of my programming efforts.  I only mention it to add to your potential bookshelf.  David Stein's book is the modern standard.

By the way, I am happy to answer any AutoLISP question you may have.  Or you can visit the [AutoDesk forums](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Visual-LISP-AutoLISP-and-General/bd-p/130) or the [AUGI forums](http://forums.augi.com/forumdisplay.php?f=91) or the [CADTutor.net forums](http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/forumdisplay.php?21-AutoLISP-Visual-LISP-amp-DCL)